# Error with Rust: cannot call a method whose type contains a self-type through an object

Tags: rust

I want to make an instance of Ord, which compares my objects by struct field. Maybe I am missing something here

```
#[deriving(Eq, Clone)]
struct SortableLine<T>{
    comparablePart: ~T,
    line: ~str
}

impl Ord for SortableLine<~Ord>{
    fn lt(&self, other: &SortableLine<~Ord>) -> bool{
        return self.comparablePart.lt(&other.comparablePart);
    }
}
```

This fails with

Thanks
    cannot call a method whose type contains a self-type through an object

Is there a way to make ordering of parent object based on ordering of a field comparison?

Comment: Consider whether you actually need the part to be stored as `~T`; `T` is likely to be a more efficient choice.

Comment: Even if T is also a str?

Comment: `str` is not a valid type. `~str` is. If you were using `struct S<T> { t: T }`, `S<~str>` would have a member `t` of type `~str`. It's also true that you could have the likes of `S<~int>` which would have `t` of type `~int`.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your type parameters are the problem; you're trying to use trait objects when that's not what you've actually got or want. Here's how you should implement it: with generics.

```
#[deriving(Eq, Clone)]
struct SortableLine<T>{
    comparable_part: ~T,
    line: ~str
}

impl<T: Ord> Ord for SortableLine<T> {
    fn lt(&self, other: &SortableLine<T>) -> bool {
        return self.comparable_part < other.comparable_part;
    }
}
```

Note two other changes:

1. I used `a < b` rather than `a.lt(&b)`. I reckon it's simpler, though it's much less important in an `Ord` impl.
2. I changed `comparablePart` to `comparable_part` (oh, and spacing in a couple of places) to fit in with standard Rust styles.

This sort of thing has the often-convenient side-effect that you don't need it to be a `SortableLine`; it can just be a `Line`, and it will be orderable if it's made of orderable parts, and not if not.

Comment: Thanks a lot, my another issue I wasn't able to find syntax
impl<T: Ord> in any tutorial. I was sticking it any other possible place when I tried to introduce T:Ord into implementation

Comment: @i.petruk: it's covered in http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/tutorial.html#generics, though the `impl<T>` part is only demonstrated once and without any bounds at that point.

Comment: Thanks, I probably haven't notice it